# Square Boxes Instead of Font Awesome Icons - CSS and Font Files Properly Linked - How to Fix?

Tags: font-awesome

"Why am I seeing square boxes instead of Font Awesome icons on my web page? I have properly linked the Font Awesome CSS and font files, but the icons are not displaying correctly. What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIX6C.png

```
<i class='fa fa-home fa-4x'></i>


 <link rel=stylesheet href="CpLayout/css/all.min.css" />
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `fa-solid fa-house` ([link](https://fontawesome.com/icons/house?f=classic&s=solid)).
The [fa-home](https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/home?f=classic&s=solid) icon is part of Font Awesome v5.

I can see that you have ChatGPT open in another tab with the name "Font Awesom...", did you use it for the icon by any chance?

ChatGPT's training data cutoff is some time late 2021, which is before Font Awesome v6 was released, so if you're using v6, you need to make sure the icons you are trying to use are part of v6 and not v5.

Here's a link you can bookmark to search for free, classic + brands icons:

https://fontawesome.com/search?o=r&m=free&f=classic%2Cbrands